# Do we need to update UI in main thread or in main queue?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I read a lot many articles which specifies that we need to update the UI in the main thread however whenever I update my UI is always the code.

`DispatchQueue.main` which in return gives me the Queue not thread. How exactly I would access the thread or both are same ?

Comment: Always update the UI on main thread. Basically MainQueue add your code block to perform on main thread.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main` allow you to add your queue your block to call it on main thread. The code inside that block won't be called immediately, but thats is to not freeze the thread it's called.

Comment: My concern is if I need to update the UI in main thread why I  am accessing main queue or accessing main queue itself is accessing main thread.

Comment: queue will add the job to the thread?

Comment: @Tj3n which indirectly means that the main queue itself is the main thread?. Or we can make the statement as in IOS programming UI update should be done on the main queue.

Comment: A queue is a list of tasks to be executed in the future.  By accessing the main queue with `DispatchQueue.main`, you are putting your task in line to be executed on the main thread when the queue manager gets around to scheduling your task.

Answer (score 23):

Imagine a train station where the number of the train is the same as the number of the platform that it leaves from.

So if you want the #1 train, you stand on #1 platform. You cannot get on the train without first standing on the platform. Everyone else who wants to get on this train also stands on the platform to wait for their chance to get on the train.

The train is the thread. The platform is the queue.

If you want to get on the main thread, get on the main queue.

Comment: One of the best explanations I've seen on this topic.

Comment: This is something called explanation, You are awesome, loved it.

Comment: That “number of the train is the same as the number of the platform” analogy suggest a 1-1 relation between queues and threads, which does not exist. Items dispatched to different (non-main) queues can execute on the same thread (even on the main thread), and different items dispatched to the same queue may execute on different threads.

Answer (score 8):

From [Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) in the Concurrency Programming Guide:

> Main dispatch queue
>
> The main dispatch queue is a globally available serial queue that executes tasks on the application’s main thread. This queue works with the application’s run loop (if one is present) to interleave the execution of queued tasks with the execution of other event sources attached to the run loop. Because it runs on your application’s main thread, the main queue is often used as a key synchronization point for an application.

Generally, GCD maintains a pool of threads, and there is no 1-1
relationship between dispatch queues and threads. But the main queue
is special: it is tied to the main thread, all items dispatched
to the main queue are executed on the main thread. (The same is
true for [`OperationQueue.main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1409193-main).)

Dispatching code to `DispatchQueue.main` (or `OperationQueue.main`)
ensures that it is executed on the main thread, and synchronized with
other UI updates.

In this sense, the terms “execute on the main thread” and
“execute on the main queue” are often used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

DispatchQueue manages the execution of the code on a specific thread.

From Apple documentation:

> DispatchQueue manages the execution of work items. Each work item
>   submitted to a queue is processed on a pool of threads managed by the
>   system.

So, when you call

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //your code
}
```

This code is submitted to the `main` queue which in turn runs on the Main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  However, if I make statement like "All UI updates must be done on main queue would make more sense rather than main thread as main thread of main queue is not accessible to application programmer.". plz guide.

Comment: The main thread and the main queue are the same for the purposes of this question (and almost all use cases), but they're not 100% identical. Also, you don't always access the main thread using the main queue, so changing the wording would just be confusing for a different class of user!

Comment: Saying that UI updates should be done on Main queue is incomplete as it limits the understanding that one should only use DispatchQueue to do UI changes. Since there are other ways in which you can perform code on Main thread. DispatchQueue is one of those ways.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenDarlington UditS. your statements seem very logical accurate now.

Answer (score 0):

//main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{ 
 //eg. 
 tableview.reloadData()
  // here you update your UI.
}
```

Comment: yes if you want to update UI of table view then add (tableview.relodedata()) otherwise as you wish. that one only example.

Comment: Did you mean [`reloadData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata)?

Comment: The method you linked to is called `reloadData`, not `relodedata`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176031/discussion-between-saxena-and-paper1111).